# Why is the first item doubled in ASP.NET CORE MVC application jquery .each loop?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am develpoing ASP.NET MVC application where I have defined PartialView like this:

```
<div class="editorRow">
<span>Name: </span> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
</div>
```

With a press of a button user can add such views to collection:

```
<div id="editorRows">
@foreach (var item in Model.Children)
{
<partial name="_myPartial" model="item" />
}
</div>
<a id="addItem" asp-action="BlankSentence" asp-controller="Home">Add Row...</a> <br />
```

These items(information that is in the PartialViews) are then to be sent back to controller with ajax function, here is a small section of the script:

```
var products = [];
$(".editorRow").each(function(index, element) {
      let inputEl = element.querySelector("input[name='Name']");
      products .push({ Name: inputEl.value });        
});
```

Problem is that the resulting products array always contain one item more then user has added to editorRows collection. First item is doubled. Why is it so? I know there are similar posts here on SO, but nothing seems to solve this particular issue.

Comment: Your question seems to be about the jquery `$(".editorRow").each` - so please provide the relevant *rendered HTML* (open page in browser, view source or inspect element).  It's most likely that you have an extra `.editorRow` somewhere that you're not expecting - viewing the *rendered HTML* will help you find the issue.  If it doesn't please [edit] your question to include that HTML - ideally in a snippet that demonstrates the issue (ie `products` has an extra value).

Comment: @freedomn-m Oh, thank you, thank you, thank you so much! In my code I had <div class="editorRow" id="editorRows">  instead of <div id="editorRows"> as I have showed here. I had absolutely no idea this would result in such behavior.